# DateRangePicker cambiar el mínimo de días tras seleccionar la primera fecha

Tags: jquery, daterangepicker

Estoy usando [DateRangePicker](https://longbill.github.io/jquery-date-range-picker/), necesitaría ayuda encontrar un modo de cambiar 'minDays' después de seleccionar la primera fecha del rango.

```
$('.mdaterange').dateRangePicker({
  ...
  minDays: 2,
  ...
}).bind('datepicker-first-date-selected', function(event, obj) {
  //change here or similar to minDays: 5
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lamentablemente el API que ofrece ese plug-in está demasiado limitado. Por lo tanto la única solución que pude encontrar fue modificar directamente el script original `jquery.daterangepicker.js`.

En la línea 986 podrás encontrar la sección donde definen el API del plug-in.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ya sabrás, los métodos que ofrece su API de manera predeterminada son: **setStart, setEnd, setDateRange, clear, close, open, redraw, getDatePicker, resetMonthsView y destroy**

Te comparto el fragmento de código que tuve que agregar (yo elegí incluirlo entre los métodos **setDateRange** y **clear**, pero tú lo puedes poner donde gustes):

```
setMinDays: function(mDays) {
    if (typeof mDays == 'number') {
        opt.minDays = mDays;
    }
}
```

Entonces, para cambiar el valor de la propiedad **minDays** se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
$('.mdaterange').data('dateRangePicker').setMinDays(5);
```

Por lo tanto, aplicándolo a tu fragmento de código, quedaría así:

```
$('.mdaterange').dateRangePicker({
  minDays: 2
}).bind('datepicker-first-date-selected', function(event, obj) {
  //change here or similar to minDays: 5
  $('.mdaterange').data('dateRangePicker').setMinDays(5);
});
```

Y aquí te comparto un ejemplo funcional: **[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emrpgtbw/)**

Comment: muy buena aproximación, gracias :)

Comment: Por nada! Un placer! =)